# What is the accuracy of the Google Glass eye tracking device? and is it accessible?

Tags: google-glass, eye-tracking

I want to know if the data stream from the eye tracker on #GoogleGlass is accessible and if so, what accuracy in detecting pupil or other eye component movement can it realistically achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Google glass as of now does not support gaze tracking. 
Perhaps we would see them in the coming versions considering that it will be a good feature to have.
Answering your question, No Google glass doesn't support Eye Tracking! In fact, it doesn't even have an EYE facing camera!

Answer (score 0):

Glass does have an eye facing cam.

Correction: not sure about the details of this "sensor".

Comment: It is suggested [on this other question's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421282/google-glass-video-input) that it has an IR facing device, not a conventional optical cam as suggested here (?).