# Google glass video input

Tags: android, google-glass

Since there is 2 cameras on the google glass (one that can record what you see, and one that track your eyes). Do you guys have any clues if it's possible to use the "eye tracking video" as an input ?

For sure, we'll have more info when the GDK is out... but I was wondering if it can be coded like a 2 sides camera on a traditional phone ?

What do you think ?

Comment: There isn't one facing the eye, there's a IR transmitter and receiver there instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly access the IR sensor which is used for the wink, etc, however there are certain eye gestures that you can capture but they don't provide a means for *eye tracking* capabilities.

For more info, take a look at [my response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175631/accessing-rear-facing-camera-on-glass/21176529#21176529) to a similar question.

Some people are doing some cool stuff with eye tracking + glass via an add-on 3D printable apparatus and pupil tracking software.  See more [here](http://www.engadget.com/2013/11/14/google-glass-eye/) and the vid [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QSn6s3DPTSg).