# Accessing rear facing camera on Glass

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I looked through the api, stackoverflow and google, and didn't find anything.   Is there a way in the API to access the camera that faces the eye?  I would like to be able to tell if the user's eye is open or closed...is this possible with this version of the GDK?

Is that what the built in wink-to-take-a-picture app is doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot currently determine open/closed, however there are some eye gestures that are supported, assuming that you have the latest version of Glass hardware.

From [here](https://gist.github.com/zhuowei/5694367), you can see the supported gestures:

```
  BLINK("BLINK", 3),
  DOFF("DOFF", 6),
  DON("DON", 5),
  DOUBLE_BLINK("DOUBLE_BLINK", 4),
  DOUBLE_WINK("DOUBLE_WINK", 2),
  NO_GESTURE("NO_GESTURE", 0),
  WINK("WINK", 1);
```

Also, on that page, they explain how you have to listen to the `com.google.glass.action.EYE_GESTURE` intent to receive the events:

> If you are writing an app, the intent to listen for is
>   `com.google.glass.action.EYE_GESTURE` . There is a public API to
>   enable/disable them in the undocumented package
>   `android.glass.GlassGestureManager` . Get it via
>   `Context.getSystemService("glass_gesture")`.

Check out winky's [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/kaze0/winky/blob/master/src/com/mikedg/android/glass/winky/MainActivity.java) for an example.

[Here's another](https://github.com/thorikawa/GlassEyeGestureDemo) eye gesture example which interacts with eye gestures.